If you swear by Allah just because I could not control mytongue about something false what should I do should I feed 10 poor people or should I fast 3
I said to my friend wallahi this is not your brother but it was

Alhamdulillah,
If the oath you mentioned in your question is an unintentional oath, you do not have to pay any expiation for it.
Allah Says:

Allâh will not call you to account for that which is unintentional in your oaths, but He will call you to account for that which your hearts have earned [2:225]

And Allah knows best!
